# MySQL: how to get distinct numbers in this way?

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL data base, I have a table(eg,T) with mac address and time (eg,2012-4-30 23:00:00). I want to filter out those mac address which appeared in this week, but not in the previous week.

How could I do that in one sentence? I tried to use multiple select, but haven't found the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the table structure, I would suggest something like:

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] Mac FROM table t
WHERE 
t.Time BETWEEN '2012-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-16 23:59:59'
AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FROM table t2 WHERE t2.Mac = t.Mac AND T2.Time BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-08 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thanks. Great "not exists", I forgot it totally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`YEARWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek).

To get records from the current week:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE YEARWEEK(your_datetime_column) = YEARWEEK(NOW());
```

To get records from previous weeks only:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE YEARWEEK(your_datetime_column) < YEARWEEK(NOW());
```

Comment: Thanks too. I never knew "YEARWEEK".

Answer (score 0):

To get the Mac Addresses that have a time in this week, but not in the previous week, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE YEARWEEK(T.Time) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
AND T.MacAddress NOT IN (
    SELECT MacAddress
    FROM T AS T2
    WHERE YEARWEEK(T2.Time) = YEARWEEK(TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK, -1, NOW())));
```

This uses the [YEARWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function as bfavaretto has already suggested, and the [TIMESTAMPADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) function to compute the previous week.